Login once and run multiple subsequent tests on that state not working
I recently started working on Playwright using Typescript. I am trying to save the authentication state and run multiple tests using the saved authentication state. I tried everything that i could found on youtube or google.
I created a login.setup.ts file.
setup('authenticate', async ({ page }) => {
    // Perform authentication steps.
    const login = new loginPageAG(page);
    await login.goToLoginPage();
    await login.login('username', 'pswd');
    await login.iAgreeButton.click();
    await page.waitForURL("url after login");
    await expect(page.locator("locator")).toBeVisible();
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
   await page.context().storageState({path: authFile});

});


I created two test cases. First test case. File name  test1.spec.ts
test.beforeEach(async ({page}) => {
    
    await page.goto("url of the site");
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
})
    

test('PomTest', async ({page}) => {
   

    const selectIndividualRehabProviderRegistaration =  new myOverviewPageAG(page);
    await specname.functionName();
    await expect(locator='value']")).toBeVisible();   

});

Second test case. File name test2.spec.ts

test.beforeEach(async ({page}) => {
    
    await page.goto("https://test-campus.dli.mn.gov/user/login");
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
})
    
test('PomTest2', async ({page}) => {   

    const abc =  new myOverviewPageAG(page);
    await specname.functionName();
    await expect(page.locator("locator")).toBeVisible();

});

In the playwright.config.ts, i did below changes
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/,
    },
        {
      name: 'chromium',      
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      storageState: './playwright/.auth/user.json'  
      //
       },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    }

But, only one test case works. 2nd test case gets stuck at login page. How can i make both cases work?

Second testcase has different URL than the First, whole concept of storage state is to use the same login authenticated state in all the tests provided if all the tests have same url. or else you have to handle it using if else based auth setup.
